# Iconv encoding conversion in Node

Tags: node.js, encoding, character-encoding, iconv

I'm using Iconv in Node.js to convert scraped HTML (via request with `binary` encoding) from `SHIFT_JIS` to `UTF-8`:

```
request({url:url, encoding:'binary'}, function (error, res, html) {

   var iconv = new Iconv('SHIFT_JIS', 'UTF-8//TRANSLIT//IGNORE')

   var converted = iconv.convert(new Buffer(html,'binary')).toString('utf8')

})
```

The conversion I'm getting back looks like:
`é«SnÌ\r\núêXj[J[ÍAVvÉÈèª¿È«³É\r\nå«ÈCpNgð^`

While the pre-conversion looks like: `���[�J�b�g����X�j�[�J�[`

I tried using `encoding:null` in the request, but that didn't work either.

Comment: Did you verify the content encoding by checking `res.headers` ?

Comment: @mscdex : res.headers `'content-type': 'text/html; charset=Shift_JIS'`

Comment: Are you using `iconv` or `iconv-lite`? Have you tried using the other module to see if that works/similarly doesn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The encoding actually works as posted above, it was an issue in handling the final response outside the request function.